# Spark: Send debug text to driver from worker

Tags: java, debugging, apache-spark

I would like to diagnose some error. I believe I should not tell the whole scenario to get a good solution for my question. So, I would like to create some debug information on the workers and display it on the driver, possibly real-time.

I read somewhere that issuing a `System.out.println("DEBUG: ...")` on a worker would produce a line in the executor log, but currently I'm having trouble retrieving those logs. Aside from that it would be still useful if I could see some debug noise on the driver as the calculation runs.

(I also figured out a workaround, but I don't know if I should apply it or not. At the end of each worker task I could append elements to a sequence file and I could monitor that, or check it at the end.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I could think of doing this is (ab)using a custom acummulator to send messages from the workers to the driver. This will get whatever String message from the workers to the driver. On the driver you'd print the contents to collect the info. It's not real-time as wished-for as it depends of the program execution.

```
import org.apache.spark.AccumulatorParam

object LineCummulatorParam extends AccumulatorParam[String] {
      def zero(value:String) : String = value
      def addInPlace(s1:String, s2:String):String = s1 + "\n" + s2
}

val debugInfo = sparkContext.accumulator("","debug info")(DebugInfoCummulatorParam)

rdd.map{rdd => ...
        ...
        ...
        //this happens on each worker
        debugInfo += "something happened here"
        }

//this happens on the driver
println(debugInfo)
```

Not sure why you cannot access the worker logs - that would be the most straightforward solution BTW.

Comment: When I try to browse for it an error message appears, because of some configuration problems. They will fix it eventually. Will try your solution tomorrow.

Comment: Will this run before collect? Just because AFAIK, until any kind of collect there will be no movement on any worker. But If I start collecting I will crash and I will not have any debug info.

Comment: No, you will indeed need to execute your computation by requesting some action on the RDD. As I mentioned, it's an 'abuse', more of a hack to get the data as requested in the question. The normal way to go would be to use `logging` and look for the logs on your workers.